aws lambda: run lambda attaching self-created image
I've been able to launch my lambda. I created and update it using jar file straightforwardly.
My jar file is generated at: ./target/frontoffice-apigateway-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-aws.jar.
However, I need to change the way I uploading code. I mean, I first need to create a docker image and push it on my ECR repository.
Here my Containerfile:
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/java:21

# Copy function code and runtime dependencies from Maven layout
COPY ./target/frontoffice-apigateway-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-aws.jar ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

# Set the CMD to your handler (could also be done as a parameter override outside of the Dockerfile)
CMD [ "org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.FunctionInvoker::handleRequest"]

And it's succesfully pushed on ECR repository.
I've created a new lambda attaching my recently pushed image, but I'm getting when it starts:
{
  "errorMessage": "Class not found: org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.FunctionInvoker",
  "errorType": "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException"
}

I've also played creating a new lambda attaching straightforwardly the jar file using aws console and code runs.
Any ideas?
